# MUI Autocomplete- on selecting an option, label shows the value instead of selected label

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a controlled MUI Autocomplete. I am using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) with Material UI Autocomplete.

I have a list of options which is rendered through Autocomplete `options` prop.

When an option is selected, I want the value to be the `id` of the selected option, and the label should show the `title`.

```
const options = [{id: 1, title: 'First'}, {id: 2, title: 'Second}];

 <ControlledAutoComplete
   control={control}
   name="Id"
   options={options}
   getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.title || option}
   label="Select Students"
   defaultValue={null}
 />
```

AutoComplete with the controller,

```
const ControlledAutoComplete = ({ options = [], label, getOptionLabel, control, defaultValue, name, renderOption }) => (
  <Controller
    name={name}
    control={control}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    onChange={([, data]) => data}
    render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
      <Autocomplete
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label={label}
            variant="standard"
            error={!!fieldState.error}
            helperText={fieldState.error?.message}
            fullWidth
          />
        )}
        {...field}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => value === undefined || value === '' || option?.id === value}
        onChange={(_, data) => field.onChange(data.id)}
      />
    )}
  />
);
```

When an option is selected, input text shows `undefined`.

Same problem happens when in the example below, it returns `data.code` instead on `data` in `onChange()`.

[Exmaple](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-6-0-1-forked-oj5khh?file=/src/MuiAutoComplete.js)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake, looking at the example you provided, you're setting `data.code` to be the new value in on the `Autocomplete` component. While when looking at the `defaultValue` you set it as a object with the **code**, **label** and **phone**.

You should change the `onChange` in the `Autocomplete` to set `data` instead of `data.code`

```js
<Autocomplete
  ...
  onChange={(e, data) => onChange(data)}
  ...
/>
```

Full controller

```js
<Controller
  render={({ onChange, ...props }) => (
    <Autocomplete
      options={countries}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => {
        return option?.label || option;
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Choose a country" variant="outlined" />
      )}
      onChange={(e, data) => onChange(data)}
      {...props}
    />
  )}
  onChange={([, data]) => data}
  defaultValue={{ code: "AF", label: "Afghanistan", phone: "93" }}
  name="country"
  control={control}
/>
```